# "error #28: expression must have a constant value" - with nRF51822 app_twi

Tags: microcontroller, c, programming, keil, nrf51822

I have been attempting to copy the nRF51822 app_twi example for own application in order to get a better understanding of how the HAL works.

However, now I have an error now that I don't understand since my code is basically identical to the example.

The error:

```
src\main.c(170): error:  #28: expression must have a constant value
```

That function where the error occurs:

```
void LSM303_read(uint8_t *m_buffer)
{
    static app_twi_transfer_t const transfers[] =
    {
        LSM303_ACC_XYZ_READ(&m_buffer[0])    /* <<<<<<<<<<<< ERROR OCCURS HERE */
        // Additional transfer go in here
    };
    static app_twi_transaction_t const transaction =
    {
    .callback            = twi_read_callback,
    .p_user_data         = NULL,
    .p_transfers         = transfers,
    .number_of_transfers = sizeof(transfers) / sizeof(transfers[0])
    };
}
```

That function causing the error, which resides in my LSM303.h header file:

```
extern uint8_t const lsm303_acc_first_reg;

#define LSM303_ACC_READ(p_reg_addr, p_buffer, byte_cnt) \
            APP_TWI_WRITE(LSM303_ADDRESS_ACCEL, p_reg_addr, 1, APP_TWI_NO_STOP), \
            APP_TWI_READ (LSM303_ADDRESS_ACCEL, p_buffer, byte_cnt, 0)

#define LSM303_ACC_XYZ_READ(p_buffer) \
            LSM303_ACC_READ(&lsm303_acc_first_reg, p_buffer, 6)
```

Not got a clue what the issue is since this is the exact same function used in the app_twi example.

Can anyone give some advice here? (I'm using Keil uvision 5 with SDK v10.0.0)

Edit:
The m_buffer they used (identical to mine)

```
// Buffer for data read from sensors.
#define BUFFER_SIZE  11
static uint8_t m_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Comment: Have you tried

   LSM303_ACC_XYZ_READ(&(m_buffer[0])) ?

and don't forget the final semi-colon.

Comment: Just gave it a try, didn't make a difference.

Comment: The final semi-colon? is just a typing error, or is on your source code?

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific with which semi-colon you mean? This is copied from my source code, so if there's an error here there's one there too!

Comment: Sorry, there isn't semi-colon error. When you call the macro, _&m_buffer[0]_ must be the same thing that _m_buffer_, and this is variable. Can you check the function used by the macros?

Comment: Edited original question to show the definition of m_buffer, theirs is identical to mine. Their macros are identical to mine with the exception of using a different register address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m_buffer` is defined as a global in the main program, therefore there is no need to pass it into the `lsm303_read` function. Doing this means that the m_buffer pointer is not constant at compile time.

Changing the function definition to take no argument resolves the problem:

```
void LSM303_read(void)
```